# Вызов класса с JButton в главный класс

Tags: java, ооп, swing

Есть 3 класса `Main` где вызывается класс `WindowApp`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowApp windowApp = new WindowApp();
        windowApp.window();
        windowApp.appMenu();
    }
}
```

Есть класс `WindowApp` в котором я хочу вызвать метод `button()` с класса `ButtonStart`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowApp {

    static JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(WindowApp.class.getResource("WindowApp/icon.png"));
    String title = "tittle";
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    void window() {
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(580, 390);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setTitle(title);
        jFrame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);



    }

    void appMenu() {

       ButtonStart buttonStart = new ButtonStart();
       buttonStart.button();    // ЗДЕСЬ Я ПЫТАЮСЬ ВЫЗВАТЬ МЕТОД button(); С КЛАССА StartButton;

    }

}
```

И есть класс `ButtonStart` в котором я хочу работать с кнопкой:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonStart extends JPanel {
    void button() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("");
        Image ph = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ButtonStart/startgame.png")).getImage();
        btn.setBounds(40, 100, 300, 150);
        btn.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ph));
        jPanel.add(btn);
    }


}
```

Вопрос:
Как правильно реализовать класс `StartButton`, чтобы я мог метод `button()` вызвать в классе `WindowApp`,а также чтобы кнопка работала в `WindowApp` окне?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что вам понравится то, что вы увидите, выполнив код, который я вам предложу. В общем и целом над приложением ещё нужно поработать. Но вы, совершенно очевидно, на правильном пути.

Обратите внимание, вы нигде не помещаете панельку, сделанную в методе button() класса ButtonStart в панельку, лежащую в фрейме WindowApp.

Для этого можно, например, получать эту панельку из метода button(). Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowApp windowApp = new WindowApp();
        //Сохраним панельку с кнопкой в переменную и передадим её формирователю окна
        JPanel bs = windowApp.appMenu();        
        windowApp.window(bs);
    }
}
```

Формирователь окна теперь должен уметь принимать панельку и **помещать её куда-то внутрь себя**:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowApp {

    static JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(WindowApp.class.getResource("WindowApp/icon.png"));
    String title = "tittle";
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    void window(JPanel bs) {
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(580, 390);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setTitle(title);
        jFrame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        jPanel.add(bs); //Собственно этого не хватало изначально

    }

    JPanel appMenu() {

       ButtonStart buttonStart = new ButtonStart();
       return buttonStart.button(); //Создадим панельку с кнопкой и вернём её в main

    }

}
```

Ну, и собственно, класс, создающий панельку с кнопкой:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonStart extends JPanel {
    JPanel button() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("");
        Image ph = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ButtonStart/startgame.png")).getImage();
        btn.setBounds(40, 100, 300, 150);
        btn.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ph));
        jPanel.add(btn);

        return jPanel; //Создали и возвращаем
    }
}
```

Мне не очень понравилось визуально то, что я увидел, выполнив код. Но кнопка появилась, а это, видимо, самое главное.

На самом деле, всё это можно сильно оптимизировать и моё решение крайне далеко от идеала (вот прям далеко). Например, очевидно, что метод appMenu() надо вызывать прямо в методе window(). Но вы уже делаете это в main. А так как вы хорошо знаете свой код, то, опираясь на него, я надеюсь, вы поймёте, чего ему не хватало.

Comment: Здравствуйте! К сожалению такой вариант реализации кода не работает..

Comment: Возможно еще есть варианты решения этого кода. может с переделанной структурой кода... Вариант решения выше, даже не компилируеться..

Comment: Перепроверил код. Всё компилируется. НО! Если у вас неправильно расположены ресурсы (вы иконки используете javax.swing.ImageIcon), то да, ничего не получится. Закоментируйте все строки, где упоминаются иконки: в WindowApp это ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(WindowApp.class.getResource("WindowApp/icon.png")); и jFrame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());, а в ButtonStart это Image ph = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ButtonStart/startgame.png")).getImage(); и btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ph));